# Is it possible to change the view range of an angular datepicker multi-year start view?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to change the view range of an angular material datepicker in a multi-year view. The default year range in a multi-year view is from 2016-2039 (24 year time range). Going backwards opens another 24-year span, 1992-2015.
I want to show 2010 as the first year of the first multi-year view. To clarify, the first view year range would be 2010-2033 (24 year time range), the previous view 1986-2009 and so on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my computer right now but i could help you with these:

```
<mat-datepicker #dp startView="multi-year" (yearSelected)="chosenYearHandler($event)" (monthSelected)="chosenMonthHandler($event, dp)"
[min]="minYear" [max]="maxYear" panelClass="example-month-picker"> </mat-datepicker>
```

According to the angular you could add yearSelected.
Try to console.log its event and see the output attribute of the selected range,then you could set the value you want in its attribute.

Comment: yearSelected is an EventEmitter that emits the selected year in multiyear view. Just in case, I did console.log the event and did not find any properties that relate to this issue.

Comment: [min]="minYear" [max]="maxYear" use these attributes to set range .